# Android Studio opens same class everytime I run app

Tags: android, android-studio

Since a couple of days Android Studio opens a specific class and goes to exactly the same line in this class as soon as I run the app from Android Studio on a device.

This only happens when some code in the project was changed. It doesn't matter whether the class was opened before or not...There is no breakpoint in this line and the code in this class is not even reached on startup. Actually Android Studio goes to this line in this class as soon as the last version of the app is closes/uninstalled by adb...

Any clue what might cause this behavior? It's really annoying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems like the reason was the file encoding, i.e. a character in this class that was not valid in the current file encoding. After changing the encoding to UTF-8 it worked again and didn't jump to the file when running the app...